# Remote desktop can't find computer name

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, internet

I'm using a win7 64 bit.

Some applications can't access the internet including Remote Desktop.
Web browsers are working fine.

I checked wireshark and there seems to be now traffic going out. So I shutdown the firewall, it didn't help.
I uninstalled the AV that didn't help either.
I noticed something strange. nslookup fails when running in powershell. I got "No response from server".  However, if I use Powershell(x86) it does work.
So I tried mstsc from both system32 and from syswow64. They both don't work.

I ran "netsh winsock reset" to no avail.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you verified the remote host is available through rdp (3389 or whatever port it was configured on?).  You say it doesn't work with 'computer name', how about with the ip address?  or trying the full qualified domain name of the host  host.domain.com.

Comment: Yes, we can connect from other computers and I tried to connect to more than one computer. Wire shark showed no traffic leaving to port 3389. So the problem is internal. I tried via IP as well.